# Error starting history server for a fresh Ambari cluster. All the data nodes are up and running

Tags: hadoop, ambari, bigdata

Ambari - 2.2.1.1, HDP - 2.3.4.7.

After a fresh cluster creation, history server cannot be started.

History server cannot be started. When we check the logs, we see

resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'curl -sS -L -w '%{http_code}' -X PUT -T /usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz 'http://url:50070/webhdfs/v1/hdp/apps/2.3.4.7-4/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz?op=CREATE&user.name=hdfs&overwrite=True&permission=444'' returned status_code=500. { "RemoteException": { "exception": "UndeclaredThrowableException", "javaClassName": "java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException", "message": null } }

We tried something more to explore to get more details:

Command: curl -X GET http://url:50070/webhdfs/v1/hdp/apps/2.3.4.7-4/mapreduce?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hdfs

output: {"FileStatus {"accessTime":0,"blockSize":0,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":16402,"group":"hdfs","length":0,"modificationTime":1462222797728,"owner":"hdfs","pathSuffix":"","permission":"555","replication":0,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"DIRECTORY"}}

When the file is put in the namenode, its exception….

Command: curl -X PUT -T /usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz 'http://url:50070/webhdfs/v1/hdp/apps/2.3.4.7-4/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz?op=CREATE&user.name=hdfs&overwrite=True&permission=444'

output: {"RemoteException":{"exception":"UndeclaredThrowableException","javaClassName":"java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException","message":null}}

But, we can list that file:

Command: ls /usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz

output: /usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz

Any pointers to solve the issue will be pretty helpful. Thanks.